# How can I get python in the command prompt on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, command-line, command-prompt

I have just installed Python on my Windows 7. I thought that after that I will be able to run python on the command prompt but it is not the case. After the installation I also found out that I can run the python command shell. This is nice. But what should I do if I want to save my program in a file and then I want to run this program (in Linux, for example, I typed "python file_name.py" in the command line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the python bin directory to your path. Follow the instructions [here](http://banagale.com/changing-your-system-path-in-windows-vista.htm) and add `c:\python26\bin` to the path (unless you installed python in a non-default location).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just need to add that python started to work from the command prompt when I use "c:\Python26" instead "c:\python\bin".

Comment: Also thanks for the link to the instructions for changing the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Is python.exe in your windows path? Try to look at the PATH environment variable and see if the installation folder of python is listed there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your environment variables to include the path to the Python executable.

On XP you can do this by right clicking on "My Computer" -> Properties and then going to the "Advanced" tab.